Why do some tags have a different description on-hover versus the description shown when you click on them?
Regarding tags at the bottom of a question, I've never noticed a difference between the on-hover tag description and the description shown when you click on that tag.  But today, I noticed that some tags have different descriptions on-hover versus what's shown when you click on them.  Why are the descriptions not the same?
For example:
The Docker tag used to have the same description on-hover that it has when you click on it:

For questions about building and running Docker containers. DOCKER
QUESTIONS MUST BE SPECIFICALLY RELATED TO SOFTWARE DEVELOPMENT.
Suitable topics include Dockerfiles, Docker Compose, and architecture.
As a rule of thumb, if your question is about something happening
inside the container, it's probably on-topic here; if it's outside the
container, it is probably off-topic.

But today, when I hover on the tag at the bottom of a question, I see a completely different description:

This change seems confusing to me, but I suspect that's because I don't understand why the tag descriptions are different depending on how you view them. Can someone please explain the difference?
